# 362J04 230AP SMD SOT23-6 PWM IC on DELL LED Monitor Power Supply

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount

Is there any way to find the datasheet for 362J04 230AP SMD SOT23-6 PWM IC of a DELL LED Monitor Power Supply? At least a close match is good.

[image: PCB top view]

*Figure 1: PCB top view*

[image: 362J04 SMD in DELL E2219 Power supply]

*Figure 2: 362J04 SMD in DELL E2219 power supply*

I could not find any reference in Google. This PWM SMD drives 4NB65 MOSFET as shown in PCB. It is the PWM.

Furthermore, [similar series SMD are available for sale in this link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000439933196.html?spm=a2g0o.search0302.0.0.75f71c9b1aAuzk&algo_pvid=8d8efbeb-aec2-475b-9259-5964fddca8f9&algo_expid=8d8efbeb-aec2-475b-9259-5964fddca8f9-1&btsid=0b0a556f16168368327223228ed4de&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_). However I could not find that datasheet also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been surfing many chip vendor's websites and spend many days without any clue. However, I was able to come to a sensible conclusion which may help you to resolve similar challenge in the future.

It was observed that there are some SOT23-6 SMDs which skip the left most digit when marking on the chip, it maybe due to the space constraints. Therefore, it was found that this 362J04 SMD is really the OB2362 PWM IC from on-bright company where first digit was omitted. Furthermore, J letter relates to the Year and 04 relates to the week as per the datasheet below. Therefore I do not need to worry about those.

[image: OB2362 datasheet]

Hence the actual IC looks like below.

[image: actual]

Finally, my second reference IC (273J38) was also inline with the same analogy.

This is how I fixed the monitor -
https://youtu.be/K0VycQafo6I